# How to move the cursor across rows of only one table among many tables in oracle database?

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

My iOS app needs to communicate with the server database. I choose Oracle 11g/ Oracle SQL developer for server database implementation. I recently learned myself about JDBC, JAVA and SQL queries. Hence my question may seem lame.
Here is my situation:

My database contains two tables (T1 and T2). I can send data to the server and store it in the database via my iOS app. Now I need to retrieve the data from the server as per app's request. For this purpose, I use a **ResultSet** variable as:

```
private ResultSet rs = SQLProcess("SELECT * FROM T1, T2");
```

Here, SQLprocess is a *public* method for ***executeQuery*** with return type **Resultset** and arguments as the columns of the two tables.The sql query for the executeQuery is as follows:

```
"SELECT a.ID '"+msg1+"', a.X '"+msg2+"', a.Y '"+msg3+"', a.Xe '"+msg4+"', a.Ye '"+msg5+"', a.SDe '"+msg6+"', a.Xs '"+msg7+"', a.Ys '"+msg8+"', a.SDs '"+msg9+"', a.Xw '"+msg10+"', a.Yw '"+msg11+"', a.SDw '"+msg12+"', a.Xn '"+msg13+"', a.Yn '"+msg14+"', a.SDn '"+msg15+"', b.ID '"+msg16+"', b.Zn '"+msg17+"' FROM T1 a , T2 b WHERE a.ID = b.ID");
```

Here, msg1 to msg17 are the arguments of the method SQLProcess (which are the columns of the two tables. msg1 to msg15 represent columns of T1 and msg16 and msg17 represent columns of T2).

The method that is responsible to send data to the client (iOS app) is given as follows:

```
void sendTo(InetAddress add) {
    try{
        DataOutputStream out = (DataOutputStream) clients.get(add);

        while(rs.next()){   
            String msg = '\n' +rs.getString(1) + "," + rs.getString(2)+ "," + rs.getString(3)+ "," + rs.getString(4)+ "," + rs.getString(5)+ "," + rs.getString(6)+ "," + rs.getString(7)+ "," + rs.getString(8) +"," + rs.getString(9)+ "," + rs.getString(10)+ "," + rs.getString(11)+ "," + rs.getString(12)+ "," + rs.getString(13)+ "," + rs.getString(14)+ "," + rs.getString(15)+ "," + rs.getString(16)+ "," + rs.getString(17)+'\n';
            System.out.println(msg);
            out.writeUTF(msg);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With this method, data are sent to the iOS app but with *mixed ways*. i.e If there are two rows in each table:

T1:

Row1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

Row2: 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

T2:

Row1: 1,16

Row2: 2,17

Then the data received at the iOS app is:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,16

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,17

2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,16

2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,17

What I need is:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,16 and 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,17.

I think that the cursor is moved to both the tables (***while(rs.next())***). Is there any way to move the cursor across rows of only one table among many tables? Or is there any other best solution for my problem?

Sorry for the lengthy post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T1, T2` without the WHERE clause actually does a [Cross Join query](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php), namely it combines each row from T1 with each row from T2. If table T1 has 100 rows and table T2 has 200 rows, you will get 100*200=20000 rows in the resultset. I'am not sure if this is your real intent.

Comment: For future reference, please don't post a test case with seventeen columns when four will do. If you want people to help you don't make them scroll your code text trying to figure out what's going on. Also, sample data with obviously different values for the two tables would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. :)

There were two 'errors' in my code:

1) I wanted to have an inner join but did cross join query. Thanks @krokodilko for the prompt comment.

2) I'm not supposed to use column name with small and capital letters together (seems invalid operation). I changed all the small characters to capital.

The new sql query is:

```
("SELECT T1.ID, T1.X, T1.Y , T1.XE , T1.YE , T1.SDE , T1.XS , T1.YS , T1.SDS , T1.XW , T1.YW , T1.SDW , T1.XN , T1.YN , T1.SDN , T2.ID , T2.ZN  FROM T1  , T2  WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID")
```